# issue to expand div width naturally to the other side end

Tags: css

I am having issues to expand the div naturally like this:

[image]

I am not allowed to use percentages. I have tried to use them, but as soon as other items go between them, the second block goes down.

**HTML code:**

```
 <div class="block1">
     <ul>
         <li>item long</li>
         <li>item small</li>
         <li>item sample</li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="block2">
     <a>This is a nice sample text</a>
 </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
 .block2{
     float:left;
     border:1px solid blue;
 }
 .block1{
     float:left;
     border:1px solid red;
 }
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjAgx/3/)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the issue is that now the div width is not as expanded layout like the picture I posted. The expected behaviour is that the width gets a natural expanded layout through the whole screen to the right side.

Comment: Yeah my bad, commented before checking the fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `float:left` by `overflow:hidden` in `.block2`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjAgx/4/)

`overflow:hidden` is a little trick to trigger block formatting layout, so that the `.block2` div sits at the side of the floated div. You can read more about block formatting contexts in [this YUI article](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/).

Comment: this is super cool, thanks for this tip! does this work on inline-block as well?

Comment: Depends on your context, `inline-block` elements don't expand (without additional properties) and usually sit at the side of each other naturally.

Comment: yeah i was fiddling with the fiddle (haha), and to make it work with `inline-block` extra declarations were needed. if i ever use `float` again i'll keep this in mind.